# Sorting specific objects in an array

Tags: ruby

I'm new to Ruby and looking to sort only certain items in my collection.
For example if I have the following array. I only want to sort the objects that contains the property `type: 'sort'`

```
   object = [{
            type: 'sort',
            id: 3
        }, {
            type: 'notsort',
            id: 4
        }, {
            type: 'sort',
            id: 1
        }, {
            type: 'sort',
            id: 0
        }
    ]
```

I need the order to map directly to the id map below.

```
sortIdOrder = [0, 1, 3]
```

The end result should look like:

```
object = [{
    type: 'notsort',
    id: 4
}, {
    type: 'sort',
    id: 0
},{
    type: 'sort',
    id: 1
}, {
    type: 'sort',
    id: 3
}]
```

As you can see the array is sorted by `id` based on the `sortIdOrder` . The `notsort` `type` can either be at the end or start.

Comment: As a note, convention holds that Ruby methods and variables should be of the form `sort_id_order`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A not very performant one-liner:

```
object.sort_by{|o| sortIdOrder.index(o[:id]) || -1}
```

This makes the `notsort` objects appear at the head of sorted array. It's an `O(m * nlog(n))` algorithm, where `n` is the size of `object` and `m` is the size of `sortIdOrder`. This is faster when your `object` and `sortIdOrder` are small.

A more performant one for large arrays is

```
order = sortIdOrder.each.with_index.with_object(Hash.new(-1)) {|(id, index), h| h[id] = index}

object.sort_by{|o| order[o[:id]]}
```

This is an O(m + nlog(n)) algorithm but requires more memory.

Answer (score 3):

Sorting can be expensive, so one should not sort when the desired order is known, as it is here.

I've assumed that the values `:id` are unique, as the question would not make sense if they were not.

First partition the hashes into those to be sorted and the rest.

```
sortees, nonsortees = object.partition { |h| h[:type] == 'sort' }
  #=> [[{:type=>"sort", :id=>3}, {:type=>"sort", :id=>1}, {:type=>"sort", :id=>0}],
  #    [{:type=>"notsort", :id=>4}]]
```

so

```
sortees
  #=> [{:type=>"sort", :id=>3}, {:type=>"sort", :id=>1}, {:type=>"sort", :id=>0}]
nonsortees
  #=> [{:type=>"notsort", :id=>4}]
```

I'll put the elements of `sortees` in the desired order then concatenate that array with `nonsortees`, putting the hashes that are not to be sorted at the end.

I order the elements of `sortees` by creating a hash with one key-value pair `g[:id]=>g` for each element `g` (a hash) of `sortees`. That allows me to use [Hash#values_at](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-values_at) to pull out the desired hashes in the specified order.

```
sortees.each_with_object({}) { |g,h| h[g[:id]] = g }.
        values_at(*sortIdOrder).
        concat(nonsortees)
  #=> [{:type=>"sort", :id=>0}, {:type=>"sort", :id=>1}, {:type=>"sort", :id=>3},
  #    {:type=>"notsort", :id=>4}]
```

Note that

```
sortees.each_with_object({}) { |g,h| h[g[:id]] = g }
  #=> {3=>{:type=>"sort", :id=>3}, 1=>{:type=>"sort", :id=>1},
  #    0=>{:type=>"sort", :id=>0}}
```

Comment: You know, `sort_by` with an `index_of` call might be the way to go here. For larger lists you'd certainly want to convert the ID order array to a hash: `Hash[array.each_with_index.to_a].invert` could do it easily.

Comment: @tadman, that's a nice use of `each_with_index` and `invert`. I must tuck that away.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `sort` with a block that sorts by `:type`, then `:id`.

```
object.sort {|a, b| [a[:type], a[:id]] <=> [b[:type], b[:id]] }

[{:type=>"notsort", :id=>4}, 
 {:type=>"sort", :id=>0}, 
 {:type=>"sort", :id=>1}, 
 {:type=>"sort", :id=>3}]
```

Comment: Thanks but I would like the order to be determined by the `sortIdOrder`. Would I just change the solution to:
`object.sort {|a, b| [a[:type], sortIdOrder.index(a[:id])] <=> [b[:type], sortIdOrder.index(b[:id])] }` ?

Comment: Cool. Some cases `type` can be nil though. Would this not work in that case?

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with something like this:

```
object.sort_by do |o|
  [
    (o[:type] == :sort) ? 0 : 1,
    sortIdOrder.index(o[:id])
  ]
end
```

When sorting by an array, you're essentially sorting by the first element, except when they're the same, in which case you sort by the second element, etc. In code above, `(o[:type] == :sort) ? 0 : 1` ensures that everything with a type of `:sort` comes first, and everything else after, even if the type is `nil`, or `5` or whatever you like. The `sortIdOrder.index(o[:id])` term ensures things are sorted as you like (though items with no `:id`, or whose `:id` is not found in `sortIdOrder` will be ordered arbitrarily. If your data set is very large, you may want to tweak this further so that the sortIdOrder array is not performed for non-sort items.

`Enumerable#sort_by` only has to call the block once for each element, and then perform fast comparisons on the results; `Enumerable#sort` has to call the block on pairs of elements, which means it's called more often:

```
irb(main):015:0> ary = %w{9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1}
=> ["9", "8", "7", "6", "5", "4", "3", "2", "1"]
irb(main):016:0> a = 0; ary.sort_by {|x| puts x; a+=1; x.to_i }; puts "Total: #{a}"
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
Total: 9
=> nil
irb(main):017:0> a = 0; ary.sort {|x,y| puts "#{x},#{y}"; a+=1; x.to_i <=> y.to_i }; puts "Total: #{a}"
9,5
5,1
8,5
2,5
7,5
3,5
6,5
4,5
6,8
8,9
7,8
6,7
1,3
3,4
2,3
1,2
Total: 16
=> nil
```

In these cases, it's really not very important, because hash access is fast anyway (though `sort_by` is *still* more legible), but in cases where calculating the attribute you want to sort by is even moderately expensive, `sort_by` can be quite a bit faster. The block form of `sort` is mostly useful if the comparison logic itself is complicated.

Comment: Thanks for answer. What if `:type` is nil ?

Comment: If `:type` might be nil, or if you have many different types besides :sort and :nosort and you want to be sure that everything but sort ends up grouped together, you'd be better off using `[(o[:type] == :sort ? 0 : 1), sortIdOrder.index(o[:id])` as your sort criterion. That'l put all of the `:sort`s at the front of the list (in the desired sort order) and everything else afterwards (in potentially arbitrary order, if their ids are missing from the `sortIdOrder` array. I'll update the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm late, but my solution is:

**Rails Solution:**

```
object.partition { |hash| hash[:id].in?(sortIdOrder) }.flatten.reverse
```

**Ruby Solution:**

```
object.partition { |hash| sortIdOrder.include? hash[:id] }.flatten.reverse
```

both of it in result give this:

```
=> [{:type=>"notsort", :id=>4},
     {:type=>"sort", :id=>0},
     {:type=>"sort", :id=>1},
     {:type=>"sort", :id=>3}]
```